# wrong python html parsing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = "http://yaz.tek.firat.edu.tr/tr/duyurular"
url_oku = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_oku, 'html.parser')
icerik = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first'})
print(kardiz)
```

my output :

```
[<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
<span class="views-field views-field-title"> <span class="field-content"><a href="/tr/node/479">Grup-1, Grup-2, Grup-3, Grup-4 ve Grup-6 Öğrencileri İçin Staj Sunum Tarihleri</a></span> </span>
<span class="views-field views-field-created"> <span class="field-content"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Salı, Aralık 5, 2017 - 09:58 </span> </span> </div>]
```

But I want to get just `" Grup-1, Grup-2, Grup-3, Grup-4 ve Grup-6 Öğrencileri İçin Staj Sunum Tarihleri "`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: where is the html file? or code?

Comment: view-source:http://tek.firat.edu.tr/

Comment: You have some copy&paste problem - should it be `icerik` or `kardiz`?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki yes u are right :/

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki i asked 1 more question on your codes comments, can u answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.text` on a result from BeautifulSoup. It takes the textual content of the elements found, skipping the tags of the elements.

e.g.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = "http://yaz.tek.firat.edu.tr/tr/duyurular"
url_oku = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_oku, 'html.parser')
icerik = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first'})
for result in icerik:
  print(result.text)
```

Comment: @Mücahit Demirhan  Great. The way this site works is that you can upvote the answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: İ want to ask again something. Now i need "/tr/node/479" part. How can i get this ?

Comment: @MücahitDemirhan, edit your question to add this part too, and I'll answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this as well to get the title and link from that page. I used css selector to get them:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

url = "http://yaz.tek.firat.edu.tr/tr/duyurular"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
for item in soup.select("#content .field-content a"):
    link = urljoin(url,item['href'])
    print("Title: {}\nLink: {}\n".format(item.text,link))
```

Partial output:

```
Title: 2017-2018 Güz Dönemi Final Sınav Programı (TASLAK)
Link: http://yaz.tek.firat.edu.tr/tr/node/481

Title: NETAŞ İşyeri Eğitimi Mülakatları Hakkında Duyuru
Link: http://yaz.tek.firat.edu.tr/tr/node/480
```